# Trying to make a AutoMod for my website script and i could use some help/info

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to make a AutoMod for my website script that i have been working on to make it easier to add mods and update to the website script. I have looked at vQmod script but it will not work with my website script so i decided to make my own AutoMod for my script using .xml pages to get the new codes to add to the script pages.

The .xml page holds the directory path, page, search code and the replace code and a few other things that is not needed right now.

But i ran in to a problem and can't figure out how to fix it.

The problem is if i have a long code like this in the .xml page for the search code

```
$counters = load_counters(); $page_title = (isset($page_title)) ? ' ' . $page_title : '';
```

and have a code like this for the replace code

```
$counters = load_counters(); $page_title = (isset($page_title)) ? ' ' . $page_title : ''; $testing;
```

It will not replace the search code in the page.

I am using str_replace() to replace the search code but it only works if i use a code like this for the search code and replace codes in the .xml page.

////This works////

Search code in the .xml page

```
$page_title = (isset($page_title)) ? ' ' . $page_title : '';
```

Replace code in the .xml page

```
$page_title = (isset($page_title)) ? ' ' . $page_title : ''; $testing;
```

and the search code will be change to the replace code in the page it is editing. But i need it to work with the first example as well.

[Here is a copy of the coding i have been working on to make my AutoMod for my website script. I know it still needs a lot of work and cleaning up but it still has a long way to go to be finished.](https://ubidzz.com/private/automod.txt)

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?